# Cannot make connection to .accdb file using python

Tags: python, odbc, database-connection, pypyodbc

I am writing a script that needs to make a connection to a microsoft access .accdb file and extract data from it.

Here is a snippet of what I am doing?

```
import pypyodbc
pypyodbc.lowercase = False

conn = pypyodbc.connect(
       r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' +
       r'DBQ=file.accdb;'
       )
cur = conn.cursor()
```

I get the following error:

```
    raise Error(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified')
```

I have installed the drivers for ODBC as instructed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development

But the error persists, any idea what should I do or where I am going wrong?

Comment: That link has instructions for connecting to SQL Server, not Access. The error message suggests that you working on a Windows machine. Is that correct?

Comment: @GordThompson That's correct!

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Office installed on that machine? If so, is it the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version?

Comment: yes, and its 32 bit

Comment: and my python is also 32-bit.

Comment: You could try running [this script](https://github.com/gordthompson/AceOdbcCheck) to see if the ODBC driver is correctly configured for third-party applications.

Comment: It says your 64-bit setup is working properly, I had 32-bit before, I installed 64-bit when 32-bit didnt work.

Comment: Try uninstalling the 64-bit driver and installing the 32-bit driver from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: @GordThompson No luck with this unfortunately :(

Comment: Does the AceOdbcCheck script show different results now?

Comment: AceOdbcCheck script?

Comment: The VBScript you ran earlier, link in a previous comment.

Comment: It says my 64-bit ODBC setup is working correctly.